# Trying to use .filter on the results of a .map function in a React component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, higher-order-functions

I'm making a cocktail recipe-book app in React and I'm trying to implement a search feature that filters out cocktails by ingredient. For my homepage, I map through each user, then each users submissions and render them on the page. I'm trying to make it so that after the second map, each submission is filtered based on what values are in the search field. Here's how I've tried to do it:

```
<div><SearchContainer>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
             </SearchContainer>

        <div style={styles.root}>
            <GridList
                cellHeight={180}
                style={styles.gridList}
                padding={50}
            >
                {this.state.users.map((user, index) => {                      
                     console.log(user.submitted) 
                    return (

                        user.submitted.map((submission, index) => {
                            return submission 
                            let filteredSubmissions = submission.filter(
                                (submission) => {
                                    return submission.recipe.toLowerCase().indexOf(
                                        this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

                                }
                            )                  
                            return (

                                    <GridTile
                                        key={filteredSubmissions._id}
                                        title={filteredSubmissions.name}

                                        subtitle={<span>{filteredSubmissions.recipe}</span>}
                                    >
                                    <img alt={filteredSubmissions.name} onClick={() => this.setState({redirect: true, submissionId: submission._id, userId: user._id})} src={submission.img} />

                                    </GridTile>   
                            )
                        }
                        )
                    )
                })}
            </GridList>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Error message:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, recipeLink, recipe, img, submittedBy, name, comments}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in GridList (at ExperimentalHomePage.js:66)
    in div (at ExperimentalHomePage.js:65)
    in div (at ExperimentalHomePage.js:61)
    in ExperimentalHomePage (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:20)
    in Switch (at App.js:19)
    in div (at App.js:17)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:16)
    in MuiThemeProvider (at App.js:15)
    in App (at index.js:7)
```

I'm not sure if I'm just not using the right syntax or if my logic is totally flawed, but if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You are returning `return submission ` before anything else. Maybe remove this first and check whether that works.

Comment: Essentialy, somewhere you are trying to render a js object instead of a jsx element and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

React can't render an object. `filteredSubmissions.recipe` looks like this is probably your culprit. Try making it a string `JSON. stringify(filteredSubmissions.recipe)` and test it again.